# How to flag all values in one cluster based on a threshold in SQL?

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I am looking for a solution to a general concept in SQL (Databricks SQL in particular, but I am happy to solve this for any flavor of SQL). It seems like a textbook problem, but I cannot simply wrap my head around it.

Image I have a table like so

```
______________________
| time | temperature |
----------------------
|    0 |           2 |
|    1 |           1 |
|    2 |           0 |
|    3 |          -1 |
|    4 |          -2 |
|    5 |          -4 |
|    6 |          -5 |
|    7 |          -3 |
|    8 |          -2 |
|    9 |          -1 |
|   10 |           1 |
|   11 |           1 |
|   12 |          -1 |
|   13 |          -2 |
|   14 |          -1 |
|   15 |           0 |
|   16 |          -2 |
|   17 |          -5 |
|   18 |           1 |
...
```

now I want to add a boolean column `flag` which flags all rows by the following rules:

1. the temperature is <= -5 or
2. the temperature is < 0 and there is a temperature <= -5 in the same cluster of consecutive negative temperatures.

The rules would result in the following table

```
______________________________
| time | temperature |  flag |
------------------------------
|    0 |           2 | false |
|    1 |           1 | false |
|    2 |           0 | false |
|    3 |          -1 |  true |
|    4 |          -2 |  true |
|    5 |          -4 |  true |
|    6 |          -5 |  true |
|    7 |          -3 |  true |
|    8 |          -2 |  true |
|    9 |          -1 |  true |
|   10 |           1 | false |
|   11 |           1 | false |
|   12 |          -1 | false |
|   13 |          -2 | false |
|   14 |          -1 | false |
|   15 |           0 | false |
|   16 |          -2 |  true |
|   17 |          -5 |  true |
|   18 |           1 | false |
...
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Sample data tip: add a second -5 cluster, to avoid malfunctioning shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, good point. I've modified the sample data.

Comment: Doesn't rule (2) include rule (1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using kind of gaps and islands query for  Sql Server, MySql, SQLite.

```
with tbl(ttime, temperature) as (
select  0 ,   2 union all
select  1 ,   1 union all
select  2 ,   0 union all
select  3 ,  -1 union all
select  4 ,  -2 union all
select  5 ,  -4 union all
select  6 ,  -4 union all
select  7 ,  -5 union all
select  8 ,  -3 union all
select  9 ,  -2 union all
select 10 ,  -1 union all
select 11 ,  -1 union all
select 12 ,   1 union all
select 13 ,   1 union all
select 14 ,  -1 union all
select 15 ,  -2 union all
select 16 ,  -1 union all
select 17 ,   0 union all
select 18 ,   1 
)
select ttime, temperature, case when min(temperature) over(partition by grp) <= -5 then 1 else 0 end flag
from (  
   select *, row_number() over(order by ttime) - row_number() over(partition by case when temperature<0 then 1 else 2 end order by ttime) grp 
   from tbl
) t  
order by ttime
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zpZyrLv_)

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. I didn't know there is a "gaps and islands" problem out there. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS have;

CREATE TABLE have
(
    t     INT
  , temp  INT
)
;

INSERT INTO have VALUES
  (0,  2)
, (1,  1)
, (2,  0)
, (3, -1)
, (4, -2)
, (5, -4)
, (6, -5)
, (7, -3)
, (8, -2)
, (9, -1)
, (10, 1)
, (11, 1)
, (12,-1)
, (13,-2)
, (14,-1)
, (15, 0)
, (16,-2)
, (17,-5)
, (18, 1)
;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t) AS one
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN temp<0 
                           THEN 0 
                           else 1 
                         END ORDER BY t) AS two 
FROM have
)
, CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *, one - two AS isl
FROM CTE
)

SELECT t, temp, CASE WHEN MIN(temp) OVER(PARTITION BY isl) <= -5
            THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'
          END as flag
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY t
;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH ClusteredTemperatures AS (
SELECT
   time,
   temperature,
   CASE
   WHEN temperature <= -5 THEN 1  -- Flag for temperatures <= -5
   ELSE 0
END AS flag
FROM your_table
),

ClusterAssignments AS (
SELECT
   time,
   temperature,
   flag,
   SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS cluster
FROM ClusteredTemperatures
),

FlaggedTemperatures AS (
SELECT
   time,
   temperature,
   flag,
   cluster,
   MAX(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY cluster) AS max_cluster_flag
 FROM ClusterAssignments
)

SELECT
 time,
 temperature,
 CASE
   WHEN temperature <= -5 THEN true
   WHEN temperature < 0 AND max_cluster_flag = 1 THEN true
   ELSE false
 END AS flag
    FROM FlaggedTemperatures
 ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However your code does not work even for the sample data...